# Systematic procedure for calculating derivatives involving Dirac delta terms

Tags: derivatives, dirac-delta

[As we know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368155/laplacians-and-dirac-delta-functions), $\nabla \cdot (\hat{r}/r^2) = 4\pi \delta^3(\vec{r})$. This particular instance is easily justified by appealing to the divergence theorem, but there are also more complicated examples such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898904/how-can-a-curl-lead-to-delta-distributions). My question is actually inspired by a post over at physics SE ([link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/644711/factor-before-diracs-%ce%b4-in-magnetic-dipole-field-formula)) where it seems that a delta function term has been left unaccounted for somehow, but I'm not sure where.

In general, derivatives are easy to calculate systematically using the chain rule, product rule, *etc.* but it seems that when the result contains Dirac delta terms, some ad hoc method is used to derive them. Is there a systematic way to do it?

Comment: @MarkViola I'd like to know if there's a way to calculate the Dirac delta terms without having to go through a whole process of reasoning about integrals. I mean a mechanical process where you just apply a set of rules to the input expression. That's how we normally calculate derivatives, but it seems that doing so omits the Dirac delta terms which are occasionally important.

Comment: Well, one must be aware that the Dirac Delta is not a function, it is a distribution.  In addition, one needs to understand that differentiation of a function is not the same as differentiation of a distribution.  The example I provided in my posted answer showed this latter point.  As a function $1/r$ has second derivatives $$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\left(\frac1r \right)=\frac{3x_ix_j -3|\vec x|^2 \delta_{ij}}{|\vec x|^5}$$ for $|x|\ne 0$ with non-existent second partial derivatives at $0$.  But as a distribution, ... (see next comment) ...

Comment: (continued from previous comment)... but as a distribution we have $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\left(\frac1r\right)=-C_{ij}\delta(\vec x)+\text{PV}\left(\frac{3x_ix_j-|x|^2\delta_{ij}}{|\vec x|^5}\right)$$

where $C_{ij}$ is given by

$$C_{ij}=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi n_i n_j \,\sin(\theta)d\theta\,d\phi$$and we see that there is a Dirac Delta component along with a Principal Value term.  So, I don't see a systematic way of evaluating a distributional derivative from methods that don't account for the distributions.

Comment: I tried to provide a somewhat systematic and rigorous way to evaluate distributional  derivatives for a wide class of problems.  Do you have something more specific in mind.  Perhaps I could help more if the scope of the question was narrowed.

Comment: As a simple example, take the function $H(t)$, the Heaviside (or unit step) function.  Its derivative is $0$ for $t\ne 0$ and does not exist at $0$.  But the distributional derivative of the distribution $H(t)$ is $\delta(t)$, the Dirac Delta.

Comment: And as a function, $H(t)$ has no Fourier Transform.  But as a tempered distribution the Fourier Transform of $H(t)$ is $\text{PV}\left(\frac{i}{\omega}\right)+\pi \delta(\omega)$.

Comment: I've added quite a bit more including a second example and a development that develops the "systematic" product rule for differentiating distributions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you mean specifically by a "systematic way to do it."  But to begin, the Dirac Delta and its derivatives are [Generalized Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function), also known as [Distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).

Distributions are linear [Functionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)) that map test functions from $C_C^\infty$ onto the reals.  For the Dirac Delta, the functional definition is given as

$$\langle \delta_a, \phi \rangle =\phi(a) \tag 1$$

where $\phi$ is a suitable test function.

---

**DERIVATIVE OF A DISTRIBUTION:**

Suppose that $T$ is a distribution.  We define the $n$'th derivative $T^{(n)}$ of $T$ such that for any $\phi\in C_C^\infty$, we have

$$\langle T^{(n)},\phi \rangle =(-1)^n\langle T,\phi^{(n)}\rangle \tag2$$

**It is important to understand the difference between a function and its distributional counterpart.  And it is, therefore, important to understand that differentiation of a function is not the same as differentiation of a distribution.**

> We can apply "systematic" rules such as the product rule for differention to distributions.  Suppose that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are distributions and that the product $T_1T_2$ is a well-defined distribution (Note that the product of distributions might not be well-defined.  For example, the product of the Dirac Delta and the Heaviside function is not defined.).  Then, we have
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \langle (T_1T_2)',\phi\rangle&=-\langle T_1T_2,\phi'\rangle\\\\
> &=-\langle T_1, T_2\phi'\rangle\\\\
> &=-\langle T_1, (T_2\phi)'-T_2'\phi\rangle\\\\
> &=\langle T_1',T_2\phi\rangle+\langle T_1,T_2'\phi\rangle\\\\
> &=\langle T_1'T_2,\phi\rangle+\langle T_1T_2',\phi\rangle\\\\
> &=\langle T_1T_2'+T_1T_2',\phi\rangle
> \end{align}$$
>
> Hence, in distribution, we assert that $(T_1T_2)'=T_1T_2'+T_1T_2'$.

In the following examples, we will systematically apply $(2)$ to determine the distributional interpretations of the (i) derivative of the Heaviside function $H$ and (ii) second mixed partials of the scalar potential function $T=\frac1{|\vec x|}$.

---

---

**EXAMPLE $(1)$:**

Let $H(t)$ denote the Heaviside (or unit step) function.  The derivative of $H(t)$ is $0$ for $t\ne 0$ and fails to exist at $0$.

As a distribution, the derivative, $H'$ of $H$ can be evaluated as follows.  Let $\phi \in C_C^\infty$.  Then, applying $(2)$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\langle H',\phi\rangle&=-\langle H, \phi'\rangle\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty H(t)\phi'(t)\,dt\\\\
&=-\int_0^\infty \phi'(t)\,dt\\\\
&=\phi(0)\tag3
\end{align}$$

whence we see from $(3)$ that in distribution $H'=\delta_0$

---

---

**EXAMPLE $2$:**

As an example, define the function $T$ as $T(|\vec x|)=\frac1{|\vec x|}$ for $|\vec x|\ne 0$.  The second mixed partial derivatives for $|\vec x|\ne 0$ are given by

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\left(\frac1{|\vec x|}\right)=\frac{3x_ix_j-|\vec x|^2\delta_{ij}}{|\vec x|^5}$$

where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker Delta.  Irrespective of how $T(0)$ is defined (or not defined), the second mixed partials of $T(|\vec x|)$ fail to exist at $0$.

Now, let $T(|\vec x|)$ be a distribution.  Using $(2)$, we see that the second partial derivatives of $T$ are given by

$$\begin{align}
\langle \partial_{ij}T, \phi\rangle &=\langle T, \partial_{ij}\phi\rangle\\\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac1{|\vec x|} \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\,d^3\vec x\\\\
&=-\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left( \frac1{|\vec x|}\right)\frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial x_j}\,d^3\vec x\\\\
&=-\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3\setminus B_\varepsilon(0)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left( \frac1{|\vec x|} \right)\frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial x_j}\,d^3\vec x\tag4
\end{align}$$

where $B_\varepsilon(0)$ is a sphere of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $0$.

---

Then integrating by parts the integral on the right-hand side of $(4)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\langle \partial_{ij}T, \phi\rangle &=-\phi(0)\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi n_i n_j \,\sin(\theta)d\theta\,d\phi+\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3\setminus B_\varepsilon(0)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}\left(\frac1{|\vec x|}\right)\phi\,d^3\vec x\\\\
&=-\frac{4\pi}{3}\phi(0)\delta_{ij}+\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3\setminus B_\varepsilon(0)}\frac{3x_ix_j-|\vec x|^2\delta_{ij}}{|\vec x|^5}\phi\,d^3\vec x\tag5
\end{align}$$

where $n_i$ is the $i$'th component of the outer unit normal to $B_\varepsilon(0)$.

---

Therefore, we see from $(5)$ and $(1)$ that in distribution we have

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\left(\frac1r\right)=-\frac{4\pi}{3}\delta_{ij}\delta_0(\vec x)+\text{PV}\left(\frac{3x_ix_j-|x|^2\delta_{ij}}{|\vec x|^5}\right)$$

---

**SPECIAL CASES:**

For $i=j$, we see that the second derivative of $\frac1{|\vec x|}$ with respect to $x$ is

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left(\frac1{|\vec x|}\right)=-\frac{4\pi}{3}\delta_0(\vec x)+\text{PV}\left(\frac{2x^2-y^2-z^2}{|\vec x|^5}\right)$$

And the Laplacian is $-4\pi \delta_0(\vec x)$ as expected.